# Why does a Torch error "Assertion `srcIndex < srcSelectDimSize` failed" only appear while training on GPU but not on CPU?

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm trying to follow this tutorial to code a seq2seq translation model with pytorch:
[Pytorch-seq2seq](https://github.com/bentrevett/pytorch-seq2seq/blob/master/6%20-%20Attention%20is%20All%20You%20Need.ipynb)

Everything works perfectly fine when I train my model on cpu. The training is done, evaluation is also done and I get good results.

However, the moment I switch to GPU, I get this error while evaluating on the first batch:

```
/pytorch/aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/Indexing.cu:662: indexSelectLargeIndex: block: [179,0,0], thread: [0,0,0] Assertion `srcIndex < srcSelectDimSize` failed.
```

```
  File "train.py", line 496, in <module>
    valid_loss = evaluate(model, valid_iterator, criterion)
  File "train.py", line 459, in evaluate
    for i, batch in enumerate(iterator):
  File "/home/miniconda3/envs/torch_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torchtext/legacy/data/iterator.py", line 160, in __iter__
    yield Batch(minibatch, self.dataset, self.device)
  File "/home/miniconda3/envs/torch_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torchtext/legacy/data/batch.py", line 34, in __init__
    setattr(self, name, field.process(batch, device=device))
  File "/home/miniconda3/envs/torch_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torchtext/legacy/data/field.py", line 231, in process
    tensor = self.numericalize(padded, device=device)
  File "/home/miniconda3/envs/torch_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torchtext/legacy/data/field.py", line 353, in numericalize
    var = torch.tensor(arr, dtype=self.dtype, device=device)
RuntimeError: CUDA error: device-side assert triggered
```

I searched through Stack and googled around, but the only answers I found is that the embedding dimensions must be wrong. Also, that I can use cpu to get the line when the error occurs. However, as I mentioned, the training on the cpu goes without any errors and the model is trained and evaluated, so I don't think there is anything wrong with the code itself.

Does anyone have any pointers as to what I can do?